# cbind a dynamic column name from a string in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to cbind a column to the data frame with the column name dynamically assigned from a string

```
y_attribute = "Survived"
cbind(test_data, y_attribute = NA)
```

this results in a new column added as `y_attribute` instead of the required `Survived` attribute which in provided as a string to the y_attribute variable. What needs to be done to get a column in the data frame with the column name provided from a variable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` to do this

```
library(dplyr)
test_data %>%
     mutate(!! y_attribute := NA)
#   col1 Survived
#1    1       NA
#2    2       NA
#3    3       NA
#4    4       NA
#5    5       NA
```

#### data

```
test_data <- data.frame(col1 = 1:5)
```

Comment: Why is the `!!` is been added here?

Comment: @Rahul It is for evaluating to get the value from the object

Answer (score 8):

You don't actually need `cbind` to add a new column. Any of these will work:

```
test_data[, y_attribute] = NA # data frame row,column syntax
test_data[y_attribute] = NA   # list syntax (would work for multiple columns at once)
test_data[[y_attribute]] = NA # list single item syntax (single column only)
```

New columns are added after the existing columns, just like `cbind`.

Comment: Actually the code is to bind the test data and the train data. `rbind(train_data, cbind(test_data, y_attribute = NA))`

Comment: So you can't nest it in one line easily, but that's no issue. `test_data[, y_attribute] = NA; rbind(train_data, test_data)`.

Comment: but with @akrun's solution, I am able to do that in a single line `rbind(train_data, mutate(.data = test_data,!! y_attribute := NA))`

Comment: Yes. If you don't actually want to modify the `test_data` data frame, you just want to add a column on anonymously to use as an input, then that is a good way to go. I'm not trying to argue one way or another, I'm just showing the `base` answer to the question as asked. Even if it doesn't actually apply to your use case, it's good to have it here for future readers.

Comment: Though personally I don't find "two nested commands in one long line" as a big difference from "two commands on two short lines". The main difference I see between our answers is whether or not changes to `test_data` are assigned to the `test_data` object or not.

Comment: You could do something like `rbind(train_data, {test_data[, y_attribute] = NA})` to force it into one line, but I wouldn't recommend it.

Comment: I would say it's an ugly hack, not a good one. But if you hate line breaks and don't much care about clarity of your code, go for it.

Answer (score 1):

Not proud of this but I usually will do somethingl like this:

```
dyn.col <- "XYZ"
cbind(test.data, UNIQUE_NAMEXXX=NA)
colnames(test.data)[colnames(test.data == 'UNIQUE_NAMEXXX')] <- dyn.col
```

Comment: It's ugly but I like it.

Comment: colnames(test.data)[colnames(test.data) == 'UNIQUE_NAMEXXX'] <- dyn.col

Answer (score 0):

We can also do it with `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(test_data)[, (y_attribute) := NA]
```